# Values in same row of groupwise maximum

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I've got a table with the most common colors in images. It looks something like this:

```
file | color  | count
---------------------
1    | ffefad | 166
1    | 443834 | 84
2    | 74758a | 3874
2    | abcdef | 228
2    | 876543 | 498
3    | 543432 | 3382
3    | abcdef | 483
```

I'm trying to get the most common color for each image. So I'd like my result to be:

```
file | color  | count
---------------------
1    | ffefad | 166
2    | 74758a | 3874
3    | 543432 | 3382
```

So my problem seems to be that I need to GROUP BY the `file` column, but MAX() the `count` column. But simply

```
SELECT h.file, h.color, MAX(h.count) FROM histogram GROUP BY h.file
```

isn't working because it's indeterminate, so the color result won't match the row from the count result.

```
SELECT h.file, h.color, MAX(h.count) FROM histogram GROUP BY h.file, h.color
```

fixes the determinacy, but now every row is "unique" and all rows are returned.

I can't figure out a way to do a subquery or join, since the only "correct" values I can figure to get, file and count, are not distinct by themselves.

Perhaps I need a saner schema? It's "my" table so I can change that if need be.

Comment: You should wait before accepting an answer; @Twelfth runs 2 to 3 times faster than AgRizzo. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82203/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tbl.file, tbl.color, tbl.count
FROM tbl
LEFT JOIN tbl as lesser
ON lesser.file = tbl.file
AND tbl.count < lesser.count
WHERE lesser.file IS NULL
order by tbl.file
```

Comment: I don't understand why this works since `file` is not a distinct field, but it does. Thanks. I think how I'm going to solve this in practice, though, is just by adding a `rank` column to the table that holds the relative rank of the color for each file so I can just do `SELECT * WHERE rank = 1`. That would also make it easy to get the most common 2, 3, N colors for each image, which I also may need to do in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
select file , max(count)
FROM histogram 
GROUP BY h.file
```

This will give the max(count) by file.  Turn it into a subquery and inner join so it acts as a filter.

```
select h.file, h.colour, h.count
from histogram inner join
(select file , max(count) as maxcount
FROM histogram 
GROUP BY h.file) a
on a.file = h.file and a.maxcount = h.count
```

This will respond with 2 rows if there are more than 1 colour with the same max count.